# How to parse international currency strings reliably with minimal code

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, currency

A bit of background - I am writing some automated user acceptance tests for a mobile application and I don't always have control over the culture of the device that the tests will be executed on.

This application deals with currencies and I was wondering what the best approach might be to parse a string with a currency amount reliably without knowing the device culture.

For example, I would like to parse €12.34 or $12.34 or £12.34 etc to a double value (or whatever).

A workaround is to ignore the first character in the string but that's not necessarily an ideal solution.

Comment: Do a google search on the following `NumberStyles.Currency` there are plenty example on the internet as well as `SO`

Comment: Thanks very much. I will give it a go!

Comment: @MethodMan - The solution proposed doesn't work in a generic way. The  currency string will be parsed according to the current culture of the environment in which the test is executed. However, the current culture and the culture/locale of the mobile device aren't necessarily always the same. Which was my question really. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @stuartd The same comment. Thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: The first character may not be enough - I have 139 currency symbols in the the cultures available, on my local PC, from `string[] currencySymbols = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)
        .Select(culture => culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol)
  .Distinct()
        .ToArray();` - and lots of them are more than 1 character long,  see http://pastebin.com/r9ks7Udm

Answer (score 1):

What I did eventually to address this was to get all possible international currency symbols as per the snippet below (thanks to stuard) and then to check my own string against each of these values.

```
string[] currencySymbols = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.A‌​llCultures).Select(culture => culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol) .Distinct() .ToArray();
```

I stripped any numeric characters, '.' and ',' from my own string, leaving just leave the currency prefix, before doing the comparison.

I'm not sure if it's the best possible solution but it works!